# how to make .toggle effect only 1 element when may have the same class

Tags: jquery

So I have the following markup

```
<div class="item-w">
    <div class="item-g">
        <div class="item-name">Aircraft Docs (ARROW)</div>
        <div class="item-action">Check</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-name">Aircraft Docs (ARROW)</div>
    <div class="item-action">Check</div>
</div>    
<div class="item-w">
    <div class="item-g">
        <div class="item-name">Weight &#38; Balance</div>
        <div class="item-action">Check</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-name">Weight &#38; Balance</div>
    <div class="item-action">Check</div>
</div>
```

And I want to "item-g" to show/hide when when "item-w" is clicked, but only for the "item-g" within that particular "item-w" div.

The jQuery I'm using is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".item-g").hide();
    });


    $(function()
      {
      $(".item-w").toggle(function()
                          { // first click shows green
                          $(".item-g").fadeIn('fast');
                          },
                          function()
                          { // next click hides green
                          $(".item-g").fadeOut('fast');
                          });
      });
</script>
```

I've also tried the following, to no avail:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".item-g").hide();
    });


    $(function()
      {
      $(".item-w").toggle(function()
                          { // first click shows green
                          $(this).next(".item-g").fadeIn('fast');
                          },
                          function()
                          { // next click hides green
                          $(this).next(".item-g").fadeOut('fast');
                          });
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`next` selects immediate next sibling of the selected element, but in your markup `.item-g` is a child element, you can use `find` or `children` method. Also note that `toggle` method is deprecated you can use `click` and `fadeToggle` methods instead.

```
$(".item-w").click(function() { 
    $(this).find(".item-g").fadeToggle('fast');
    // $(".item-g", this).fadeToggle('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
    $(this).children(".item-g").animation_function();
```

So only the child element of `this` is affected.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(function()
{
   $(".item-w").toggle(function()
   { // first click shows green
      $(this).find(".item-g").fadeIn('fast');
   },
   function()
   { // next click hides green
      $(this).find(".item-g").fadeOut('fast');
   });
});
```

I made a jsfiddle if you get confused.

http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewDavis/WnB62/